# Insert delimiter between each character in a string and repeat each letter using an increasing counter

Tags: php, string, loops, repeat, delimited

I just want my loop to run, but when I try to do it, it fails. It has to increment each letter by an increasing amount based on how many iterations have occurred while looping, but it doesn't take any new letters at all.

Why is this happening and what is the reason? In C++, such code would work.

```php
function accum('ZpglnRxqenU') {
    // your code
    $result = '';
    $letters_result = '';
    $letter_original = '';
    $num_if_str = strlen($s);
    $j = 0;
    for ( $i=0; $i <= $num_if_str; $i++ )
    {
        $letter_original = substr($s, $i, $i+1);
        $j = 0;
        while ($j == $i)
        {
            $letters_result = $letters_result . $letter_original;
            $j++;
        }
        if ($i != strlen($s))
        {
            $letters_result = $letters_result . '-';
        }

    }
    return $letters_result;
}
```

It returns: `Z-----------`

Expected:

```
Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu
```

Comment: How do you call the function to get that result???

Comment: Indenting code properly will help...

Comment: ZpglnRxqenU thiss

Comment: what is `$s`? Where has it been defined?

Comment: That is not a valid function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems here:

- you're using `$s` but never initialise it
- Your call to `substr()` uses an incorrect value for the length of substring to return
- you're inner loop only runs while `$i = $j`, but you initialise `$j` to 0 so it will only run when `$i` is zero, i.e. for the first letter of the string.

There is a simpler way to do this. In PHP you can address individual characters in a string as if they were array elements, so no need for `substr()`

Further, you can use `str_repeat()` to generate the repeating strings, and if you store the expanded strings in an array you can join them all with `implode()`.

Lastly, combining `ucwords()` and `strtolower()` returns the required case.

Putting it all together we get

```
<?php

$str = "ZpglnRxqenU";
$output = [];
for ($i = 0;$i<strlen($str);$i++) {
    $output[] = str_repeat($str[$i], $i+1);
}
$output = ucwords(strtolower(implode('-',$output)),"-");

echo $output;   // Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu
```

Demo:https://3v4l.org/OoukZ

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much more to add to @TangentiallyPerpendicular's answer as far as critique, other than you've made the classic `while($i<=strlen($s))` off-by-one blunder. String `bar` will have a length of 3, but arrays are zero-indexed [eg: `[ 0 => 'b', 1 => 'a', '2' => 'r' ]`] so when you hit `$i == strlen()` at 3, that's an error.

Aside from that your approach, when corrected and made concise, would look like:

```php
function accum($input) {
    $result = '';
    for ( $i=0, $len=strlen($input); $i < $len; $i++ ) {
        $letter = substr($input, $i, 1);
        for( $j=0; $j<=$i; $j++ ) {
            $result .= $letter;
        }
        if($i != $len-1) {
            $result .= '-';
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(accum('ZpglnRxqenU'));
```

Output:

```
string(76) "Z-pp-ggg-llll-nnnnn-RRRRRR-xxxxxxx-qqqqqqqq-eeeeeeeee-nnnnnnnnnn-UUUUUUUUUUU"
```

Also keep in mind that functions have their own isolated variable scope, so you don't need to namespace variables like `$letters_foo` which can make your code a bit confusing to the eye.

Answer (score 0):

For a direct "string in, string out" functional approach, `preg_replace_callback()` can be used to delimit and expand each letter after the first.  Use `mb_convert_case()` to force all delimited letter sequences to be in title case.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6EJoQ))

```
var_export(
    mb_convert_case(
        preg_replace_callback(
            '/(?!^)./',
            function($m) {
                static $i = 1;
                $m[0] = '-' . str_repeat($m[0], ++$i);
                return $m[0];
            },
            $input
        ),
        MB_CASE_TITLE
    )
);
```

---

Otherwise, use a classic `for()` loop with `str_repeat()` calls to build a temporary array, then implode and apply title casing. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/iaSKf)

```
$array = [];
for ($i = 0, $length = strlen($input); $i < $length; ++$i) {
    $array[] = str_repeat($input[$i], $i + 1);
}
var_export(
    mb_convert_case(
        implode('-', $array),
        MB_CASE_TITLE
    )
);
```